# Vue.js enterprise application framework layout / menu

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to `Vue.js`. I'm going to migrate an application we did a few years ago using `ExtJS` framework. As some developers might know, `ExtJS` used to be a great framework for building nice `SPA` applications with a lot of already built in visual components that help you to reduce development time. But, since Progresive Application Frameworks are now the way to go, we decided to start migrating this application. Server side won't change so thats a huge advantage because this will only be client side work.

The actual application looks like this:

[image]

On the left we have a collapsible menu that is built on the fly based on the user permissions. Every element (object) in the menu has the route for opening a new tab with the specific module.

[image]

We know that we might not get the same look & feel using `Bootstrap` 3x or 4x but at least we need to have the same left menu and on the right a way to open multiple tabs that are going to be each module or option clicked from the left menu.

I have been trying to find a sample code or project that can let us start with a good template.

How can this approach can be implemented using Vue.js, how easy would be to use the router to do the Tabs functionality? Does anyone have already done something like this using Vue.js?

> Any advice or recommendation is really apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nested subroutes must fit well in this case I believe.

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: Layout,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'today',
          component: Incidents,
          name: 'incidents'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

In order to preserve the open tabs you can use URL params as an array: ?openTab[]=incidents&openTab[]=Assistance

Using the get params you can construct the list of open tabs; and the active tab is coming from the router.

Content of the closed tabs can be loaded using dynamic `component`s: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components